# Where's this "Unit Analysis View"?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

When I finish an autopsy, the research report ends with

> We may be able to gain further insight into this creature's unique abilities in combat if another specimen is targeted in the field in the Unit Analysis View.

Where is this view? Is it something available at my base or only in combat?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Found it, I think. It's not called "Unit Analysis View" anywhere else, but this seems to be what the research reports refer to:

[image]

This comes up when you hit "More Info" after choosing an attack-related action.

Comment: The hotkey for it is F1 when targeting an enemy.

Comment: Okay, what does this view give you then? More info about how to kill it?

Comment: @mist basically, yeah. It gives you information about the abilities the alien has and what affects your ability to hit them.

Comment: But you have to psionically control the alien to see that. That's the tiny bit of info everyone omits. It might be obvious for you, it wasn't for me.

Comment: @mist Eh? Not that I know if. You might have to research the alien first, but I'm pretty sure you don't have to control the alien at the time of inspection. (Can't test it right now, though - not anywhere near a computer that can run the game right now.)

Comment: You don't have to use psionic.  You just need to have done an autopsy.